# Is this query from database using EF correct?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework

Can i ask if this is the correct way to delete the whole database table using EF? 
Department table joins Facility with DepartmentID,
Facility table joins Facility Reservation with FacilityID,
I need to delete all the record from Facility Reservation table.
Can someone please guide me and tell me if this is correct?
Thank you!

```
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    "DELETE FacilityReservation FROM Department INNER JOIN Facility ON Department.DepartmentID = Facility.DepartmentID " +
                        "INNER JOIN FacilityReservation ON Facility.FacilityID = FacilityReservation.FacilityID WHERE Department.DepartmentID =" + departmentID);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, certainly not, you need a DELETE FROM <TABLENAME>, and when you do a join, you need another "FROM <Table>".

You probably want this:

```
DELETE FROM FacilityReservation 

INNER JOIN Facility 
    ON Facility.FacilityID = FacilityReservation.FacilityID 

INNER JOIN Department 
    ON Department.DepartmentID = Facility.DepartmentID 

WHERE Department.DepartmentID = @departmentID;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your SQL statement, it looks like the DepartmentID can be retrieved from your Facility table. Therefore, your SQL statement could be something fairly simple, like:

```
DELETE a
FROM FacilityReservation a
INNER JOIN Facility b ON a.FacilityID = b.FacilityID
WHERE b.DepartmentID = @departmentID
```

[See SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/588362/1)